# How many doors are on each floor?

Tags: dungeon-of-the-endless

Let's say I'm on Floor 2 in Dungeon of the Endless. I've opened 4 doors, and I need to decide whether my 3-per-door industry module will pay for itself by the time I reach the exit.

How many doors can I expect on each floor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I analyzed the associated section from the GameConfig.xml according to some information that was provided [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/249050/discussions/0/613935404243171281/#c613936039345877948).

```
<!-- ============= DUNGEON ROOM COUNT ============= -->
<DungeonRoomCountMin>
    <CurveOperation Type="Multiplication">
        <Curve Abscissa="Level">
            <CurvePoint X="1" Y="12" Link="true" />
            <CurvePoint X="8" Y="26" Link="true" />
            <CurvePoint X="11" Y="28" Factor="0" />
        </Curve>
        <Curve Abscissa="PlayerCount" BaseValue="1">
        </Curve>
    </CurveOperation>
</DungeonRoomCountMin>

<DungeonRoomCountMax>
    <CurveOperation Type="Multiplication">
        <Curve Abscissa="Level">
            <CurvePoint X="1" Y="16" Link="true" />
            <CurvePoint X="9" Y="32" Link="true" />
            <CurvePoint X="12" Y="34" Factor="0" />
        </Curve>
        <Curve Abscissa="PlayerCount" BaseValue="1">
        </Curve>
    </CurveOperation>
</DungeonRoomCountMax>
```

I entered the given values (in bold) into a table and extrapolated the missing values. **Link="true"** means that linear interpolation between two successive values is used. **Factor="0"** sets the slope to 0, so following values stay the same.

[image: Table]

[image: Graph]

Comment: Matches the "thumb" rule: 12+2*level.

Comment: [Only 27 doors on Floor 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujYAu.png) - I have found a mistake in the table on the 11th floor there could be only 27 doors see attached picture.

Answer (score 7):

> About the "41" limit: sadly, there is a limitation in our dungeon generator. Because we defined the global possible shapes of each floor, you can exceed this (partly random) limit with the XML value. The limit is higher in the upper floors.

This was posted by a developer in [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/249050/discussions/0/613935404243171281/?insideModal=1#c613936039345877948) question on the same thing.

Basically, it's a partially random number that has a limit that increases the more levels you go through. There is no set number of doors per level.

---

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/249050/discussions/0/613935404243171281/?insideModal=1#c613936039345877948)

Comment: How is this an answer?